# insufficient funds for gas * price + value even though balance is way more than gas * price + value

Tags: web3js, infura

Getting this error only on some of the wallets I tried. Too low is for sure not the problem. Working on infura.

```
sendEth = async function(fromm, frommPUB){
      fromAcc = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(fromm);
      allTokWals2 = $('#adtokens')[0].getElementsByClassName('adtokens-itm');
      var toAddLen = document.getElementsByClassName('sendtokens-itm').length;
      var nonceCo = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(frommPUB);

      var gasToUse = 21000;

      for (var i = 0; i < allTokWals2.length; i++) {
        gCost = allTokWals2[i].getAttribute('gascost');
        if (toAddLen > 1) {
          gCost = gCost*toAddLen;
        }
        gCost = gCost*tokenDefGwei* 1e9;//10 gwei
        var pubKey= allTokWals2[i].getElementsByClassName('adtokens-public')[0].value;//send to

        if (retok.test(pubKey)) {
          await web3.eth.getBalance(frommPUB, (err, resp) => {
            if(err!=null){
              console.log(err)
            }else{
              console.log('eth balance:    '+web3.utils.fromWei(resp.toString(), 'ether'));
            }
          });

          console.log('eth to send  '+gCost);
          console.log('Tx fee  '+(21000*tokenDefGwei * 1e9));
          console.log('Actual cost in eth  '+web3.utils.fromWei(((gasToUse*tokenDefGwei * 1e9)+gCost).toString(), 'ether'));
          console.log('nonce Count  '+nonceCo);
          await web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(fromm);
          web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({to:pubKey, chainId: 1, value:gCost, gas: gasToUse, gasPrice: tokenDefGwei * 1e9, nonce: nonceCo+i}, fromm, function(err, r) {
            console.log(r);
            if (err != null) {
              console.log(err);
            }else {
              web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(r.rawTransaction, function(errs, receipt) {
                if (errs != null) {
                  console.log(errs);
                }else {
                  web3.eth.getBalance($('#ethAdd').val(), function(err, balance) {
                    $('#ethRem').text('eth balance: '+window.ethDecim(balance));
                  });
                }
                console.log(receipt);
              });
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug.
Private key needs to start with '0x' :|